# Sinatra: How to password protect entire site with ONLY password, and not a basic HTTP auth?

Tags: authentication, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app that I want to password protect on a very basic level. The basic idea is that there would be a page with a single input box where you would type in a password. If the correct password in submitted, then you have access to the rest of the site. If you tried to access the site without the password, it should redirect you to the password page.

I can do this with a basic HTTP Auth:

```
use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
  password == 'password'
end
```

but I want to have a decent looking page for only the password, rather than using the HTTP authentication.

Is there a gem/method to do this easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple to implement something like this. But since I had the same problem in the beginning I help you out here.

```
use Rack::Session::Pool 

helpers do
    def loged? ; session["isLogdIn"] == true; end
    def protected! ; halt 401 unless admin? ; end
end

get "/login/?" do
    erb :login
end

post '/login/?' do
    if params['password'] == "mypassword"
        session["isLogdIn"] = true
        redirect '/'
    else
        halt 401
    end
end

get('/logout/?'){ session["isLogdIn"] = false ; redirect '/' }

get 'myprotectedpage' do
    protected!
    erb :view
end
```

Of course you can extend this an hash the password and so on.

A gem which does such things is https://github.com/hassox/warden but I never used it.